# Is the following .htpasswd .htaccess login SSL protected?

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, https, .htpasswd

I have a directory that I have protected using .htpasswd/.htaccess HTTP authentication.
In the .htaccess file for the directory I have this:

```
SSLRequireSSL

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

AuthUserFile /var/www/xyz/.htpasswd
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

When I go to a page in the protected directory I am forced to https by the SSLRequireSSL directive which is as I hoped.
This means that at the point that I am challenged for login credentials the browser (Firefox) address always starts with HTTPS://. This is great but the SSL indicating padlock symbol is not present until after I enter the credentials and enter the page in the protected directory.

I am worried that this could mean that the password I enter is somehow being sent before the SSL connection is formed and is therefore passed in plain text rather than SSL encoded.

Is this a valid concern? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, all should be SSL encrypted.  If you were using an untrusted certificate, you'd be able to observe that the certificate trust warning appears before the login prompt.

The initial `401` response that prompts for your credentials would be a `403` if it were on an unencrypted channel.  Because the `SSLRequireSSL` is in place, you're definitely safe.